# ggplot histogram by hour

Tags: r, ggplot2, histogram

I am trying to plot a ggplot histogram where x = hour and y = count.

When I run the following code, the result is not what I expected:

```
ggplot(ride_bytime, aes(x = trip_hour)) +
  geom_histogram()
```

[image: histogram]

FYI **ride_bytime** data frame looks as below:

[image: data]

Comment: Seems like you probably want a bar plot, not a histogram, try `ggplot(ride_bytime, aes(x = trip_hour, y = num_rides)) +
  geom_col()`. Histograms are when you want the plot to automatically bin the data and produce a density (where the total area of all the bars is 1). Bar plots are when you have a bar for each value, and you want a count on the y-axis.

Comment: Would you explain what you expect?

Comment: @GregorThomas Thanks! Do I have to use a bar plot here because hour is a discrete variable? Also, what's the difference between geom_col() and geom_bar()?

Comment: `geom_bar` and `geom_col` are basically the same, but with different defaults. `geom_bar` uses `stat = "count"` as the default, so the height of the bar is the count of rows with that value, and you don't need to say `y = <some_data_column>`. `geom_col` requires you to specify `y = <some_data_column>`, and it will then use that data column for the height of the bars. Since you already have `num_rides` in your data, `geom_col` is perfect, though you could use `geom_bar(stat = "identity")` (as long as you put `y = num_rides` inside `aes()`).

Comment: @GregorThomas Thanks for your clarification sir.

Comment: Are you able to provide the full data frame or recreate the problem using one of the R datasets?